# Explanation of ::-1 in lists

Tags: python, list

I can reverse list order by using the `reversed` iterator or by using ::-1, as shown in this code:

```
li=[1,2,3]

print(list(reversed(li)))
print(li[::-1])
```

However, I have not understodde the meaning of the `::` addressing, and I have not found any documentation on this feature (possible due to the fact that searching for :: creates problems).

Can anyone help? Thank you.

Comment: The good old alien smiley slice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's an example of slicing. In Python, it's done like `list[start:stop:step]`.Take a look at [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation) for more details. In particular, note that the -1 is the step, meaning that it reverses how the list is traversed.